# Is this necessary to check the object nil before alloc it?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages

objective c question, I have an pointer NSObject *abc;
I haven't alloc and init it in the init method. 
So, do I need to do this in the method?

```
-(void)someThingElse{
 if(abc != nil){
    [abc release];
    abc = nil;
 }

 abc = [[NSObject alloc] init];

}
```

Is my flow right? thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your code could be simplified to:

```
[abc release];
abc = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

because

- sending a `-release` message to `nil` does nothing, so no need to check for `nil`
- no need to set `abc` to `nil` if you're just about to assign to it

You might also consider declaring `abc` as an objective-c property with `retain` semantics, in which case all you would do is:

```
self.abc = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

In either case, your `dealloc` method should also include an `[abc release]`, of course